# How to pass itteration id value to to another component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system, aura-iteration, bind-variable

I have an iteration from where I want to display a component and cant seem to get the values displaying from my other component Error: Unable to get value for key 'opleiding.Id'. No value provider was found for 'opleiding'

Sending Component:

```
  <aura:attribute name="opleiding" type="Opleiding__c[]"/>

               <aura:iteration items="{!v.opleidingen}" var="opleiding">
                           <aura:if isTrue="{!opleiding.Opleidingsduur__c!='Dagdeel'}">
                               <c:Opleidingkaart  message="{!v.opleiding}"/>
                     </aura:if>  
                </aura:iteration>
```

Receiving component:

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="message" type="Opleiding__c[]"/>
       opleiding = message
    <li>
        <a href="{! '#/sObject/' + opleiding.Id + '/view'}">
            <p>Cursus:{!opleiding.Name}</p>
            <p>Categorie:{!opleiding.Categorie__c}</p>
            <p>Startdatum:{!opleiding.Startdatum__c}</p>
            <p>Regio:{!opleiding.Regio__c}</p>
            <p>Type cursus:{!opleiding.Opleidingstype__c }</p>
            <p>Cursusduur:{!opleiding.Opleidingsduur__c}</p>
            <p>Diploma:{!opleiding.Diploma__c}</p>
            <p>Actief:{!opleiding.Actief__c}</p>
        </a>
    </li>
</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to pass in just as single record, and reference it in the componetn:

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="message" type="Opleiding__c"/>
       opleiding = message
    <li>
        <a href="{! '#/sObject/' + v.message.Id + '/view'}">
            <p>Cursus:{!v.message.Name}</p>
            <p>Categorie:{!v.message.Categorie__c}</p>
            <p>Startdatum:{!v.message.Startdatum__c}</p>
            <p>Regio:{!v.message.Regio__c}</p>
            <p>Type cursus:{!v.message.Opleidingstype__c }</p>
            <p>Cursusduur:{!v.message.Opleidingsduur__c}</p>
            <p>Diploma:{!v.message.Diploma__c}</p>
            <p>Actief:{!v.message.Actief__c}</p>
        </a>
    </li>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: the error is gone but I do not get the values

Comment: tried a differnt combinations but still cant get the values?